# pull to refresh listview duplicated when pulled android

Tags: android, listview, pull-to-refresh

I got a strange error with pull to refresh listview , when i pull the listview to refresh the list duplicated above the last list and when i scroll list will scroll new list not old , how i got this error and how process it

```
private void InitializeListPost(){
    listPostsAdapter = new ListPostsAdapter(activity, posts, this);
    listview_Posts_postsfragment.setAdapter(listPostsAdapter);
    listview_Posts_postsfragment.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                listview_Posts_postsfragment.onRefreshComplete();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

[image]

Comment: try clearing adapter values before adding refreshed values

Comment: Didn't get what exactly the issue is! Can you please check your question again? I guess your question is you are getting duplicate data while pulling the refresh view.

Comment: Your backing data list "posts" has duplicate data in it

Comment: can't find the clear method in my adapter , my adapter extends BaseAdapter , and you see i call the constructor so i didn't need to clear adapter

Comment: list posts not duplicated